# How can I add attributes to the codesample pre block that is created by tinymce

Tags: attributes, tinymce

I have a TLDR switch on my blog.
This switch is a javascript that hides any element with the class="tldr" attribute attached to it, or unhides it.

I've created custom block_formats in TinyMCE for Paragraphs that will let me create a Paragraph with the TLDR class attached.

However, when I insert a codesample using that plugin it will generate a pre block that I can not format afterward.
I've already tried to create a custom PRE block with the TLDR class but TinyMCE won't let me apply this format to the code sample block that has been created.

Does anyone have another solution for my problem or can you see if I'm doing anything wrong?
Is there another way in TinyMCE to add attributes to elements that have been added to the code already?
I've tried the code viewer but that doesn't allow me to modify the generated HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `formats` and `style_formats` to customize the styling options available to users and how they operate.

To add a custom `pre` block with `class="tldr"`, you can add this config to TinyMCE:

```
style_formats: [
    // Adds a pre format to style_formats that applies a 'tldr' class
    { title: 'TLDR', block: 'pre', classes: 'tldr' }
]
```

See this TinyMCE fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Ikhaab

On its own, this will override the default style formats, but you can add them back in and position the new TLDR option within the Blocks submenu as shown here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Jkhaab

Resources:

- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#style_formats
- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/#formats
- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/format-custom/

Comment: Hi Ben,
Thank you so much for taking the time to respond to me.
Actually I already had created a pre block as a style_format with the TLDR class option, maybe I didn't mention it clearly enough in my post.

The problem is that you can't apply this newly created style format on pre block that has been created by the "codesample" plugin.
I took the liberty to modify your fiddle so you can see it for yourself.
Do you have any other idea's how I might realize this ? I'm really stuck and can't push this new feature until I have this fixed.
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Jkhaab/1

Comment: After you create the pre block with the codesample plugin, you can open "Source code" from the View menu and add the class to the HTML there.

Comment: Hi Ben,
Thanks! I've tried that before but I added another class attribute and that didn't work.
Putting 2 classes inside the class attribute does work and is the best solution for now! thanks so much for helping me out.
In the mean time i've also created an issue on github which hopefully will allow this feature to be implemented. https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/5722